# How to set up a Grafana alert for a panel with >80% threshold value?

Tags: grafana

I am creating grafana alert to notifiy a person if threshold value crosses 80% of scrape duration
How to create alert in Grafana for specific panel if threshold value is more than 80%.

Cannot enter percentage value in threshold field, is there any alternative for it ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnz9o.png)